# Connect ADF to ServiceNow URL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am fairly new to Azure, but I have been doing ETL for quite some time now. I want to connect ADF to ServiceNow to bring in lists to our SQL data warehouse. Does anyone have any good articles or what the settings are on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in ADF which supports [Service Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-servicenow) as input source and [Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)(formerly Azure SQL Data Warehouse) as output sink.

Since you are new to ADF,based on above tutorials,i'm afraid that there are 3 elements you should get know when you execute copy activity.

1.Linked Service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services

2.Dataset:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services

3.Pipeline:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

If you want to execute pipeline in the schedule, you also could add time trigger onto specific pipeline.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I've done all of that. The problem is i don't understand the connection to servicenow. I thought i had posted the error, but it looks like it was removed?? Can you tell me if this is the correct url? https://company.service-now.com/api/now/Incident

Comment: THis is the error that i get The HttpStatusCode 401 indicates failure. {"error":{"message":"User Not Authenticated","detail":"Required to provide Auth information"},"status":"failure"} . Activity ID: 8d13e61e-b170-4d06-9563-710e9e23d8f6